# Why Wicket redirects to the home page after tomcat restarting?

Tags: wicket

Let's say I have three pages in my application: SignInPage, HomePage and AnotherPage.
When I open the application for the first time it shows me SignInPage. After authorization it redirects me at HomePage. After that, I manually open AnotherPage, restart the servlet container, and press F5 button. And wicket redirects me at HomePage again, not in AnotherPage. Why is this happens and how to avoid that?

--

All pages mounted with `mountPage` method. Each page is statefull and has @AuthorizeInstantiation annotation. The application class extends AuthenticatedWebApplication and overrides methods like this:

```
@Override
protected Class<? extends WebPage> getSignInPageClass() {
    return SignInPage.class;
}

@Override
public Class<? extends Page> getHomePage() {
    return HomePage.class;
}
```

Also, in the config I have the following row:

```
getApplicationSettings().setPageExpiredErrorPage(ErrorSessionExpiredPage.class);
```

(But I've never seen this page open)

**Update:**

The solution is to add the following code to the SignInPage class:

```
@Override
protected void onBeforeRender() {
    if (((AuthenticatedWebSession)Session.get()).isSignedIn()) {
        continueToOriginalDestination();
        setResponsePage(Application.get().getHomePage());
    }
    super.onBeforeRender();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you restart the servlet container it looses all its sessions. On the next request Wicket detects that this is a new http session and should redirect you to the SignInPage, not directly to the HomePage. Only after successful authentication you should see the HomePage.

If you use `Component#redirectToInterceptPage(Page)` + `Component.continueToOriginalDestination()` then you can land at AnotherPage after successful authentication. See `Component.continueToOriginalDestination()`'s javadoc for more information.

Answer (score 1):

restarting the servlet container gives you new session without information which pages expired so that's why you are redirected to HomePage.

Please check this: https://users.wicket.apache.narkive.com/3OtYz8xj/pageexpiredexception-not-working-on-session-expired-wicket-1-5-11